# How to check if my range has filter option on the headers

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following code

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AJ2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
```

Basically, what I want to do, is first check if that range of data has the filter option applied to them or not (I'm not checking if the data has been filtered, I'm checking if the filter option has been applied to the headers so that the arrow going down icon is next to the headers of my table) so then I can run the part of my code that does the Autofilter.

[image]

I tried the following

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").FilterMode Then Sheets("Sheet1").ShowAllData
```

but that doesn't work, because it is checking that the data has been filtered, and what I want do to do is check that the filter option has been applied to the headers (no matter if the data hasn't been filtered itself)

Note: I want to check that the whole range has the filter option applied to it, if for example only A2:D2 has the filter option applied then that won't work, it has to be A2:AJ2 specifically.

Answer (score 1):

This checks if the sheet has an Autofilter in place but won't recognize the filter of a table:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Me
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:J2")
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then rng.AutoFilter 'it doesn't matter where you (de)activate the filter on
    rng.AutoFilter '(re)activate it
End Sub
```

However, I noticed it doesn't check if it has the filter in place of A2:J2 specifically and would get rid of it even when it was correct.
This following one checks whether the range address is the same as the one you want (and does nothing if it was already set):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Set ws = Me
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:J2")
    
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        If ws.AutoFilter.Range.Address <> rng.Address Then
            rng.AutoFilter
            rng.AutoFilter
        End If
    Else
        rng.AutoFilter
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me

```
If Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = True Then    
    Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AJ2").AutoFilter    
Else
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:AJ2").AutoFilter    
End If
```